# How to make a MVC login and main view using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to ask which is the best way to manage multiple views in ExtJS 4.2 using MVC pattern.

I mean, if i must have a login form and then when someone got logged I must change to another view, how could I must do that?

Must I put Login and the other view into a ViewPort? Do anyone has any example how I could manage this? What structure do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Login should be an independent View. Here is an example how you can structure your MVC code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'xxx',
    models: [
        // ...
    ],
    views: [
        // ...    
    ],
    stores: [
        // ...
    ],
    controllers: [
        // ...
    ],

    // ...

    launch: function() {
        // at the beginning show only the login form
        this.showLoginView();
    },
    // when the login is successfull, show your main view
    login: function(username, password) {
        this.showMainView();
    }
});
```